# How to have a sum-type (ADT) with a known set of string literals?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to write code in the following spirit:

```
data EventTable = "table1" | "table2" | "some_other_table"

case eventTable of 
  "table1" -> -- do something
  "table2" -> -- do something else
  "some_other_table" -> -- do something else
  "unknown_table"-> -- SHOULD NOT COMPILE
```

I'm trying to work directly with the string literals that a remote API provides, instead of first mapping them to a regular Haskell sum-type/ADT and having to write serialisation and deserialisation functions for it.

Comment: I don't think you can't do this. You can play around a bit with overloaded string literals (see the GHC extension), but I'm unsure how far you will get, or whether this is a good idea to begin with. One might also use a string-indexed GADT, but again I'm not convinced -- it looks too complex when a basic solution exists (mapping to a regular sum type).

Comment: chi: I have 30 such fields, each having at least 10 values. What's the fastest way to get this done?

Comment: If you need to autogenerate that many sum types, each with many fields, you could exploit Template Haskell to do the metaprogramming job. TH can autogenerate the sum types and the parsers / unparsers, in principle. I'm not fluent enough in it to provide a good example.

Comment: Maybe an enumeration to keys and a mapping to the string literals?  Or a constructor that checks `elem`?

Answer (score 3):

Haskell doesn't have anything like TypeScript's [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) (which are singleton types: TypeScript will only allow you to use a given string if it can tell that you've checked the string does indeed fit the type), and the best way is probably to just hand-roll a regular datatype and a simple smart constructor. But as @chi points out in the comments, if you have a lot of strings to deal with this is probably a job for code generation.

We'll write a Template Haskell helper to turn splices like

```
stringLitTy "Foo" ["bar", "baz"]
```

into a `data` declaration, a smart constructor, and a `toString` function:

```
data Foo = Bar | Baz deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show, Read)

mkFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
mkFoo "bar" = Just Bar
mkFoo "baz" = Just Baz
mkFoo _ = Nothing

fooToString :: Foo -> String
fooToString Bar = "bar"
fooToString Baz = "baz"
```

The code to do this is simple enough, so if you're not familiar with TH this'll be a good crash course.

First let's create some names for the type and the functions, and a mapping from the string literals to some constructor names.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module StringLit where

import Data.Char
import Language.Haskell.TH

legaliseCon :: String -> String
legaliseCon (x:xs) = toUpper x : map (\c -> if not (isAlphaNum c) then '_' else c) xs

legaliseFun :: String -> String
legaliseFun (x:xs) = toLower x : map (\c -> if not (isAlphaNum c) then '_' else c) xs

stringLitTy :: String -> [String] -> Q [Dec]
stringLitTy typeName strs =
    let tyName = mkName $ legaliseCon typeName
        constrName = mkName $ legaliseFun ("mk" ++ typeName)
        toStringName = mkName $ legaliseFun (typeName ++ "ToString")
        conNames = [(n, mkName $ legaliseCon n) | n <- strs]
    in sequenceA [
        mkDataDecl tyName (map snd conNames),
        mkConstrDecl constrName conNames,
        mkToStringDecl toStringName conNames
        ]
```

`legaliseCon` and `legaliseFun` are blunt instruments to get a string into a form which is valid for a constructor or a function. (There's definitely room for improvement there!) `stringLitTy` calls `mkDataDecl`, `mkConstrDecl` and `mkToStringDecl`, below, to generate the top-level declarations. They're all pretty simple: `mkDataDecl` calls [`dataD`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:dataD) to construct the datatype declaration with an appropriate `deriving` clause.

```
enumClasses = sequenceA [
    [t| Eq |],
    [t| Ord |],
    [t| Bounded |],
    [t| Enum |],
    [t| Show |],
    [t| Read |]
    ]

mkDataDecl :: Name -> [Name] -> Q Dec
mkDataDecl tyName conNames =
    dataD
        (return [])                     -- datatype context
        tyName                          -- name
        []                              -- type parameters
        Nothing                         -- kind annotation
        [normalC n [] | n <- conNames]  -- constructors, none of which have any parameters
        enumClasses                     -- "deriving" classes
```

`mkConstrDecl` uses [`funD`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:funD) to generate the code for the smart constructor (`mkFoo`), based on the mapping from strings to the generated constructors' names.

```
mkConstrDecl :: Name -> [(String, Name)] -> Q Dec
mkConstrDecl name map = funD name $ [
    clause
        [litP $ stringL str]                          -- the string literal pattern on the LHS
        (normalB $ appE [| Just |] (conE con))        -- Just Con on the RHS
        []                                            -- where clauses
    | (str, con) <- map]
    ++ [clause [wildP] (normalB $ [| Nothing |]) []]  -- mkFoo _ = Nothing
```

And `mkToStringDecl` does much the same, except the constructors are on the left hand side and the string literals are on the right. And there's need for a wildcard clause or the `Maybe`.

```
mkToStringDecl :: Name -> [(String, Name)] -> Q Dec
mkToStringDecl name map = funD name [
    clause
        [conP con []]
        (normalB $ litE $ stringL str)
        []
    | (str, con) <- map]
```

So, if I import `StringLit` in another module and write a splice,

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Test where

import StringLitTy

stringLitTy "EventTable" ["table1", "table2", "some_other_table"]
```

I can perform case analysis on the constructors of the generated `EventTable` type. It's not exactly what you asked for in the question, but I think it gets you 90% of the way there.

```
tableNumber Table1 = Just 1
tableNumber Table2 = Just 2
tableNumber Some_other_table = Nothing

-- for good measure:
ghci> :l Test
[1 of 2] Compiling StringLitTy      ( StringLitTy.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Test             ( Test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Test, StringLitTy.

ghci> :bro
data EventTable = Table1 | Table2 | Some_other_table
mkEventTable :: [Char] -> Maybe EventTable
eventTableToString :: EventTable -> [Char]

ghci> tableNumber Table1
Just 1
```

Oh, one more thing: since the `Q` monad [allows you to run `IO` actions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:runIO) in your splices, you can (say) query the database to get your table names. Template Haskell programming is "just programming", so you can do all the usual `Monad` stuff with `Q` (like `traverse`):

```
getTablesFromDb :: IO [(String, [String])]
getTablesFromDb = {- ... -}
mkTables :: Q [Dec]
mkTables = do
    tables <- runIO getTablesFromDb
    concat <$> traverse (uncurry stringLitTy) tables
```